# Help me to ask a better question

Tags: support, specific-question

Clearly I am just not getting it with regards to asking good questions because once more my question is disapproved of.

Would some kindly soul gently educate me as to how I can make this a better question: [How do I obtain an iterative object reference to the root object in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28730842/passing-an-iterative-object-reference-to-the-factory-in-php)

Thank you.

Comment: I just want to note that someone entered a close vote for "unclear what you are asking" on that question, so that _might_ be something to look at.

Comment: Unclear? Okay, so I need to think about how I can be clearer. Thank you. I will do that.

Comment: Just curious, have you checked out the [ask] article, and the links at the bottom of the page? You'll find some good tips there that should help you with your question writing in the future. Kudos for trying to learn and improve. :)

Comment: I have but I shall go there again because it seems I may need to absorb more of that knowledge. I have tried to clarify my question which I hope did not make it too verbose.

Comment: Also worth looking at: [Do not use signature, taglines, or greetings.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior)

Comment: I have updated the question to reflect progress (which I hope clarifies what I am trying to do) and also edited the title to be in the form of a direct question. Am I moving in the right direction?

Answer (score -2):

This is probably less important, but note that your example title isn't actually phrased like a question; it is a statement with a question mark at the end.